# CSS problem only in IE

Tags: php, css, internet-explorer, google-chrome

I've created a web site [www.qwik-facts.com](http://www.qwik-facts.com) which is being seen as I want it in chrome, firefox and safari.
However, in IE it gets messed up.

I know I should be more specific, but I just can't figure out what the problem is.
Can someone take a look and point me in the right directon?

Thanks!

Comment: Given the broad nature of the question, and that it seems to be primarily about the aesthetics of, rather than code-behind, a site, this question *might* be better suited to Doctype.com. I'd also recommend checking the validity of the code (http://http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http://www.qwik-facts.com/ reports 42 errors).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might want to make your site W3 compliant/Valid.
Take a look at this:
http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http://www.qwik-facts.com/&charset=(detect+automatically)&doctype=Inline&group=0

You have 42 Errors, 45 warning(s). If you fix all of them, mainly the errors then you should start to see your site become concurrent across browsers.

Answer (score 2):

No doctype = complete waste of time trying to match between browsers.

Answer (score 1):

To start off, you should be specifying a valid doctype to put all modern browsers into standards mode. Also, you should validate your html to make sure your markup is correct.